# Javascript Forge Crypto Library: recreating public and private keys for later reuse

Tags: javascript, cryptography

In the [Forge Javascript Cryptography Library](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge), I am having a difficult time figuring out how to reconstruct a the private and public keys after I have used them. I have attempted the following:

```
var rsa = forge.pki.rsa;
var keypair = rsa.generateKeyPair({bits: 2048, e: 0x10001});
var ct = keypair.publicKey.encrypt("Arbitrary Message Here");
keypair.privateKey.decrypt(ct);
```

Which outputs: `"Arbitrary Message Here"` as expected. I have tried to reconstruct the public key this way:

```
var nVal = JSON.stringify(keypair.publicKey.n);
var eVal = JSON.stringify(keypair.publicKey.e);
var nwRsa = rsa.setPublicKey(JSON.parse(nHere), JSON.parse(eHere));
var nwCt = nwRsa.encrypt("Arbitrary Message Here");
```

When I try to encrypt the message again, I get an error:

```
"TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'bitLength'"
```

I'm not sure why though, as I believe I have used the method correctly:

```
/**
 * Sets an RSA public key from BigIntegers modulus and exponent.
 *
 * @param n the modulus.
 * @param e the exponent.
 *
 * @return the public key.
 */
pki.setRsaPublicKey = pki.rsa.setPublicKey = function(n, e) {
  var key = {
    n: n,
    e: e
  };
```

And I haven't even tried reconstructing the private key yet. I'm not sure what I'm not doing correctly, could anyone please help me? As always thanks in advance!

**Additional Afterthough:** here are the files I'm importing in my html page, I believe I've resolved all dependency issues, but I just in case (beware, they are not in alphabetical order, but in order of dependency):

```
<script src="forge/util.js"></script>
<script src="forge/debug.js"></script>
<script src="forge/jsbn.js"></script>
<script src="forge/oids.js"></script>
<script src="forge/asn1.js"></script>
<script src="forge/sha1.js"></script>
<script src="forge/sha256.js"></script>
<script src="forge/md5.js"></script>
<script src="forge/md.js"></script> 
<script src="forge/aes.js"></script>
<script src="forge/prng.js"></script>
<script src="forge/random.js"></script>
<script src="forge/jsbn.js"></script> 
<script src="forge/pkcs1.js"></script>
<script src="forge/rsa.js"></script>

<script src="forge/des.js"></script>
<script src="forge/rc2.js"></script>
<script src="forge/pbe.js"></script>
<script src="forge/pem.js"></script>
<script src="forge/hmac.js"></script>
<script src="forge/pbkdf2.js"></script>
<script src="forge/pkcs7asn1.js"></script>
<script src="forge/pkcs12.js"></script>
<script src="forge/pss.js"></script>
<script src="forge/mgf1.js"></script>
<script src="forge/mgf.js"></script>
<script src="forge/x509.js"></script>
<script src="forge/pki.js"></script>
```

TL;DR: In Forge, how does one give their public key to someone else, and how should one store their private key for multiple uses?

Comment: Please consider this article: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Comment: Thank you, I have actually read this article. This is not for a web app that will run continually on many environments that I cannot account for. This is just for a google chrome extension that I am writing as part of a school project.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was lucky enough to get in contact with the developer by raising an [issue on Github](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/issues/87). He gave me the correct methods to use, and they all seem to work. Directly quoting, here is the correct usage:

> The easiest and most compatible way to transmit public keys or to
>   store private keys is to convert them to PEM format. Private keys may
>   be optionally encrypted when converting them (by using a different
>   method, see below).
>
> Converting a public key to/from PEM:
>
> ```
> // convert a Forge public key to PEM-format
> var pem = pki.publicKeyToPem(publicKey);
>
> // convert a PEM-formatted public key to a Forge public key
> var publicKey = pki.publicKeyFromPem(pem); Converting a private key to/from PEM:
>
> // convert a Forge private key to PEM-format
> // (preferred method if you don't want encryption)
> var pem = pki.privateKeyToPem(privateKey);
>
> // wraps and encrypts a Forge private key and outputs it in PEM format
> // (preferred method if you do want encryption)
> var pem = pki.encryptRsaPrivateKey(privateKey, 'password');
>
> // encrypts a Forge private key and outputs it in PEM format using OpenSSL's
> // proprietary legacy format + encapsulated PEM headers (DEK-Info)
> // (perhaps more compatible with some legacy OpenSSL-based applications)
> var pem = pki.encryptRsaPrivateKey(privateKey, 'password', {legacy: true});
>
> // decrypts a PEM-formatted, encrypted private key
> var privateKey = pki.decryptRsaPrivateKey(pem, 'password');
> ```

Comment: Very helpful!  I needed to add `var pki = forge.pki;` before this would work, though.  Also... if you're looking to not load in unnecessary modules, I found these are the minimal dependencies that are needed to perform these actions: util, jsbn, oids, asn1, sha256, cipher, cipherModes, aes, prng, random, rsa, pem, x509, pki

Comment: And to load private key pem without password it is: `var privateKey = pki.privateKeyFromPem(pem);`